# QT5: Drawing rect on top of another rect using drawPixMap()

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qpixmap

am I using `drawPixmap()` correctly?

Essentially my goal is to take an tileset image, and replace an individual tile with a custom tile image.

I'm able to get both images to load on the screen, but when I call `drawPixmap()`, then original image doesn't change at all.

Thanks in advance.

```
void replaceCustomTile(QPixmap custom, QPixmap target, int whichTile) {
    QRect rect(0, 0 + (squareTileSize * whichTile), squareTileSize, squareTileSize);
    QRect customRect = custom.rect();
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawPixmap(rect, target, customRect);
    painter.end();
}
```

EDIT:

This is how replaceCustomTile is called:

```
QPixmap terrainTiles(":/static/Terrain.png");
QPixmap customTile(":/static/Smiles.png");
replaceCustomTile(customTile, terrainTiles, 0);
```

Comment: How do you call `replaceCustomTile()`?

Comment: `replaceCustomTile()` should be called from the event handler `::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)`. To draw `customTile` it should be provided as the second argument to such `drawPixmap` version. It is not clear why you provide two different pixmaps to that function.

Comment: Maybe I understood you incorrectly. Do you want to draw it on a widget or you want just change part of `target` pixmap by `custom` and keep the result as another pixmap?

Comment: @OrestHera Yes, sorry for the confusion. I want to change part of the target by custom. Either keeping the result as a pixmap is fine, or overwriting the existing target pixmap is fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To intialize `QPainter` by `this` it must be called from the widget `paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` if you want to draw it on some widget. So, `replaceCustomTile()` should be called from the event handler in that case.

To draw some pixmap on top of another pixmap `QPainter` should be initialized by the target pixmap using `QPainter::begin()`:

```
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&target);
painter.drawPixmap(rect, custom);
painter.end();
```

The above code draws `QPixmap custom` into given `QRect rect` over `QPixmap target`. The `target` is modified.

Comment: Although the solution is not exactly what I expected, I thought that it would remove the existing tile, but this solution simply overlays the custom over rect. Is there a quick way to replace it?

Comment: Nevermind, found the solution to erase.. `eraseRect()`

Comment: @Mickey You can also check [`QPainter::setCompositionMode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#setCompositionMode) with `QPainter::CompositionMode_Clear` (or `QPainter::CompositionMode_Source`) before `drawPixmap`.